# Displaying randomized data in android Studio

Tags: java, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to create an app where data is pulled from a website and then displayed for the user to interact with. I've successfully pulled data from the website but I'm still new to android studio and am having trouble with displaying what I want. If someone knows what I'm doing wrong and could help that would be awesome. I'm using java.

```
package com.example.boardswipe;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    Button button;   //logout button

    Button save_tab_btn;
    FirebaseUser user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     //All of the Activity.java files come with this, just ignore it
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        button = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();   //get the user
        if(user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);  //logout and go to login page if null
            startActivity(intent);              //start login activity page
            finish();                           //finish current activity
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();      //sign out user from firebase
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);  //logout and go to login page
                startActivity(intent);              //start login activity page
                finish();                           //finish current activity
            }
        });

        //code for if the save tab button is clicked --> go to that page
        save_tab_btn = findViewById(R.id.Saves_Tab);
        save_tab_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent savebtn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SavesTab.class);
                startActivity(savebtn);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Create and add profile views to the container
        int hundredThousand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int countHThou = 0;
        int tenThousand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int countTenThou = 0;
        int thousand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int countThou = 0;
        int hundred = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int countHun = 0;
        int ten = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int countTen = 0;
        int one = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int countOne = 0;


        ArrayList<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();

        while (countHThou != 11) {
            while (countTenThou != 11) {
                while (countThou != 11) {
                    while (countHun != 11) {
                        while (countTen != 11) {
                            while (countOne != 11) {
                                try{
                                    Profile profile = new Profile(one, ten, hundred, thousand, tenThousand, hundredThousand);
                                    profiles.add(profile);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.console();
                                }
                                one++;
                                if (one == 10) {
                                    one = 0;
                                }
                                countOne++;
                            }
                            countTen++;
                            ten++;
                            if (ten == 10) {
                                ten = 0;
                            }
                            countOne = 0;
                            one = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                        }
                        countHun++;
                        hundred++;
                        if (hundred == 10) {
                            hundred = 0;
                        }
                        countTen = 0;
                        ten = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                    }
                    countThou++;
                    thousand++;
                    if (thousand == 10) {
                        thousand = 0;
                    }
                    countHun = 0;
                    hundred = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                }
                countTenThou++;
                tenThousand++;
                if (tenThousand == 10) {
                    tenThousand = 0;
                }
                countThou = 0;
                thousand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
            countHThou++;
            hundredThousand++;
            if (hundredThousand == 10) {
                hundredThousand = 0;
            }
            countTenThou = 0;
            tenThousand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }

        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        TextView description = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView gameImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView players = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView playTime = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        for(Profile profile : profiles){
            gameImage.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(profile.getImageURL()));

            description.setText(profile.getDescriptionText());

            String minMaxPlayers = "Players: " + profile.getMinPlayersValue() + " - " + profile.getMaxPlayersValue();
            players.setText(minMaxPlayers);

            String minMaxPlayTime = "Time: " + profile.getMinPlaytimeValue() + " - " + profile.getMaxPlaytimeValue();
            playTime.setText(minMaxPlayTime);

            layout.addView(gameImage);
            layout.addView(description);
            layout.addView(players);
            layout.addView(playTime);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            Log.e("src",src);
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="681dp"
        android:text="@string/boardswipe"
        android:textColor="#1C37D1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FA4810"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Saves_Tab"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#5FDDD2"
        android:text="Saves"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BG_Tab"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        android:text="BoardGames"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <!-- This is a comment, everything below is hardcoded and not from database (TEMPORARY) -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="289dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arnak" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="289dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.44"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.447" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="314dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="230dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="383dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="208dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="383dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried messing with the layout things, messing with the xml file and various different layout things. None of these have worked and none are displaying what I want.